# if insert error in oracle trigger creation?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
  CREATE TRIGGER Background_Process_Report_trit
AFTER INSERT
ON Background_Process_Report
FOR EACH ROW
IF INSERT(PROCESS_NAME)
BEGIN
    SET EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP := NEW.TIMESTAMP; 
END;
/
```

process_name -- column in my Background_Process_Report table.but i want to update the each time the process_name is created(by java application), trigger update the time in the EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP table.
but it is throwing the compliation error..

error:

```
IF INSERT(PROCESS_NAME)
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
```

how to reslove this error

Comment: What do you want `IF INSERT(PROCESS_NAME)` to do?

Answer (score 4):

If EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP is a table as you say, then it must have a column you want to update, let's call it TIMESTAMP_COL.  The the trigger would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Background_Process_Report_trit
AFTER INSERT
ON Background_Process_Report
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.PROCESS_NAME IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP
    SET TIMESTAMP_COL = NEW.TIMESTAMP
    WHERE ???;  -- Change ??? to the appropriate condition
END;
/
```

I have assumed that by "IF INSERT(PROCESS_NAME)" you mean "if a non-null value is inserted into PROCESS_NAME" and created a WHEN clause to match.